# Encrypt the data in a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, database, security, encryption

Is there any algorithm exist in the sql server to encrypt the data. I have a password field which i need to encrypt but i have to encrypt the data once its being passed in the stored procedure. It means i cannot pass the encrypted data from my c# code.

```
CREATE PROC saveData(@p1 VARCHAR(50),
                 @p2 VARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @encryptedP1 VARCHAR(50)

  SET @encryptedP1=dbo.fnEncrypt(@p1)  --ENCRYPTING THE DATA WITH AN INBUILT FUNCTION

  INSERT INTO table1
              (column1,
               column2)
  VALUES     (@encryptedP1,
              @p2)
END
```

Comment: Encrypt is ambiguous. What encryption algorithm do you want to use? Where will the private and public keys be stored? Does it need to be encrypted or cryptographically hashed?

Comment: suggest me which is the best for the security purpose

Comment: It depends on what you need to do with the data. If you ever will need to recover passwords, as opposed to simply resetting them, then hashing is out of the question.

Comment: yes, i want to decrypt it back.

Answer (score 8):

This is a very fast example. It works with **Asymmetric Key**. I hope this can help.

**First off:** Create your asymmetric Key using this code:

---

```
USE [yourDB]

GO

CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY ClaveAsym

WITH ALGORITHM = RSA_2048 ---->Take a look in this type of algorithms

ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'yourKey'

GO
```

Remember this, you must to declare a variable always that you want to **decrypt** or **encrypt**

```
DECLARE @KEYID INT
SET @KEYID = AsymKey_ID('ClaveAsym')
```

---

**Decrypting data**

```
SELECT columnA, CAST(DecryptByAsymKey(@keyid, columnUser, N'yourKey') AS VARCHAR(100)),
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), DECRYPTBYASYMKEY(@keyId, columnPass, N'yourKey'))
FROM yourTable
```

---

**Encrypting Data**

```
DECLARE @User VARCHAR(MAX), @pass VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @User = 'yourUser'

sET @pass = 'yourPass'

DECLARE @KEYID INT SET @KEYID = AsymKey_ID('ClaveAsym') 

INSERT INTO yourTable( User, passw) VALUES EncryptByAsymKey (@keyid, @User ), EncryptByAsymKey (@keyid, @pass))
```

Answer (score 5):

As usual, good old Pinal Dave has some [useful information on this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/28/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-encryption-and-symmetric-key-encryption-tutorial-with-script/). It's a little involved but if you **must** do it in SQL Server then rather than in client side code then it should do the job for you. You might want to keep an eye out for performance issues though as it's quite a CPU intensive process.

Comment: Understatement of the year. It's generally not a good idea to do this kind of processing on the Database server. (annotation not a critique)

Comment: Downvoter - care to comment? The original question asked about encryption IN SQL Server which is what he got. Seems a bit mean to downvote just because you don't agree its a good idea. Heck I even pointed that out...

Comment: @Simon:search lead me here,you may want to add relevant info from the links

Comment: @Simon:search lead me here,you may want to add relevant info from the links

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a salted sha1 or md5

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', 'email@dot.com'), 2)
```

Although hashing is not technically encryption.

Comment: I already mentioned that, i am not allowed encryption/decryption in c#

Comment: This is a hash, not encryption. Also, you can execute SHA1 and MD5 both in SQL.